# Photoswipe close gallery button code

Tags: button, photoswipe

I have already tried to close the Photoswipe screen gallery using history.go(-1); but it takes me to the previous screen where my gallery was. How can I close the Photoswipe screen gallery using code staying in the page where I call my gallery? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do it with this line:

```
window.Code.PhotoSwipe.activeInstances[0].instance.hide();
```

Comment: for photoswipe v.1.0.11 the correct code is window.Code.PhotoSwipe.Current.hide();